# Stereo rectification problem with OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, stereo-3d, multiview

```py
    import cv2
    import glob
    import argparse
    import math
    from numpy import genfromtxt
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import os.path
    from scipy import ndimage
    import os


    left = cv2.imread('D:/input image 1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    right = cv2.imread('D:/input image 2.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    #left = (left/256).astype('uint8')
    #right = (right/256).astype('uint8')


    cameraMatrix1 = np.array([[1485.8503101355045, 0, 641.0072474534551], [0, 1486.8249802291273, 454.1981417235667], [0, 0, 1]])
    cameraMatrix2 = np.array([[1472.34425902698, 0, 656.7358738783742], [0, 1473.184475795988, 441.016803589085], [0, 0, 1]])
    distCoeffs1 = np.array([-0.09236217303671054, 0.15801009565677457, 0.0020679941868083445, -0.0023435708660260184, 0.04491629603683055])
    distCoeffs2 = np.array([-0.09949068652688753, 0.22953391558591676, 0.0016749995113326907, -0.0015940937703328348, -0.13603886268508916])
    rotationMatrix = np.array([[0.9999169807005986, 0.0026862926847088424, -0.012602203704541104],[-0.002633967055223802, 0.9999878496600472, 0.0041668633079119935],[0.012613243997904163, -0.004133323588458492, 0.9999119069757908]])
    transVector = np.array([29.96389633009774, 0.5883268401189343, -5.0370190999346365])
    essentialMatrix = np.array([[-0.005846632380824811, 5.0345261532342365, 0.6092635826971343], [-5.4145428656773165, 0.11031957194242471, -29.897779179091888], [-0.6672019134164675, 29.96195184048419, 0.1322696748639909]])
    fundMatrix = np.array([[4.567507458136527e-08, -3.930495370357416e-05, 0.010750771532659317], [4.227537878312907e-05, -8.607826196991683e-07, 0.3201405456504413], [-0.010999824926761303, -0.3182113833954986, 1]])


    flags = cv2.CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY
    image_size = left.shape[::-1]

    R1, R2, P1, P2, Q, roi1, roi2 = cv2.stereoRectify(cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, image_size, rotationMatrix, transVector, flags = flags)

    leftmapX, leftmapY = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, R1, P1, image_size, cv2.CV_32FC1)
    rightmapX, rightmapY = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R2, P2, image_size, cv2.CV_32FC1)

    left_remap = cv2.remap(left, leftmapX, leftmapY, cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
    right_remap = cv2.remap(right, leftmapX, rightmapY, cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)


    # For some reason, the images get rotated upside down after remapping, and I have to invert them back
    left_remap = ndimage.rotate(left_remap,180)
    right_remap = ndimage.rotate(right_remap,180)

    for line in range(0, int(right_remap.shape[0] / 20)):
        left_remap[line * 20, :] = 0
        right_remap[line * 20, :] = 0

    cv2.namedWindow('output images', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('output images', np.hstack([left_remap, right_remap]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm working on rectification of 5 different lenses on horizontal as well as vertical direction (i.e. I need all the common points exactly in the same position in the images from all 5 lenses). While I tested stereo recitifcation with two of my lenses which were placed much farther horizontally than vertically, cv2.stereoRectify always interprets them as though they were separated vertically. I want to be able to tell the function to interpret it horizontally. I've seen some similar questions posted here, but couldn't find helpful replies anywhere.

**Edit:** I've added all the distortion coefficients and calibration matrices in the code for ease of replication. These values were obtained by using a large number of calibration images and a function cv2.stereoCalibrate, but it was not possible to upload all those images and code for coefficient extraction.

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJjtX.jpg)

[input image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH5Vi.jpg)

[input image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AA7l.jpg)

[clarifying the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z0x5.png)

Comment: I am guessing your calibration code has some errors. Here are some errors I spotted in the code above:
`right_remap = cv2.remap(right, rightmapX, rightmapY, cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)`

For unknown output inversion, you need to flip your Rotation and Translation vectors:
`cv2.stereoRectify(cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, image_size, rotationMatrix.T, -transVector, flags = flags)`

If the dataset is opensource, you can provide the link here.

Comment: @SriRaghuMalireddi The output rotation problem got fixed actually when I realized the calibration and rectification algorithm work in a certain order of left and right and that I have to provide left and right images accordingly. As for the dataset, as they are just squared checkerboard images, I will upload them as soon as they're handy.

Comment: The left and right images order explains why the {R,T} inversion worked.

Comment: @SriRaghuMalireddi As I've been investigating more about stereo-rectification, I'm now wondering if the steroRectify function actually aligns them in the direction that has more disparity (meaning if my entire question was legitimate at all?). Because I found out that the stereo rectification process actually provides inputs to the disparity map (which means the images remapped after the stereo-rectification process don't cross-match each other entirely or even almost entirely). Is this correct?

Comment: StereoRectification uses the information from both the cameras (obtained during the calibration) to project the images into a single view plane. This means that both the images should be aligned, in any possible direction, as if they are stitched together. So, OpenCV's stereoRectification should do the same. The only reason where there is a possibility of stereo rectification not working properly is there are bugs in the code or your calibration phase is wrong.

Comment: @SriRaghuMalireddi So based on what you just said, there's no way to able to play with the code and make it align my images in one particular direction? Because that is my main concern. It's not that the code isn't working; it does work but not in the direction that has pixels farther apart (it aligns them in the direction which has only a very little difference in pixel position while theoretically, there should not have been any difference in that direction).

Answer (score 0):

modify this in `image_size`

```
image_size = left.shape[::-1][1:3]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).